# How to deconstruct a parameter that contains a special character?

Tags: javascript, escaping, destructuring, query-string

I am using `querysString.parse` to deconstruct the URL parameters, and some of them have brackets `[]`.

This is part of the string that I am deconstructing `title=wasabi&calories=50&nutrients%5BCA%5D=500`

`nutrients%5BCA%5D` this is the parameter I need to deconstruct, but I don't know how to escape the special characters. I know I have to rename it, but I need to access it first!

```
const { title, nutrients%5BCA%5D : nutritiant  } = querysString.parse(location.search)
```

Any ideas how do I do that?

Comment: Similar to object literal syntax, putting quotes around the "property name" is allowed, to write non-identifier names.

Comment: Also: be consistent with your spelling otherwise you'll run into trouble. `nutritiant` is not the same as `nutrients`.

Comment: When I put quotes, I get `undefined`.

Comment: I assume you are using [node's querystring](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html#querystringparsestr-sep-eq-options), which would decode uri components, and you'd get a property "nutrients[CA]", not "nutrients%5BCA%5D".

Comment: @ASDFGerte You're right. `nutrients[CA]` works! Thank you.